# Determine if app was opened by clicking push notification or by clicking app icon

Tags: swift, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have seen a lot of questions on here about this problem, but none of them accurately answered the question.

Is there a way to check if the app was opened by the user clicking on the push notification or if it was opened by the user clicking the app icon on the homepage. I need my code to do different things for the different scenarios.

A lot of people have been saying to use the didReceiveRemoteNotification, which only checks to see if a notification was received. Nothing about if the notification was pushed.

Comment: I figured it out. You need to use `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)` and check it by using `if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter

Answer (score 2):

To see how your app was launched, in your application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) check the launchOptions key. For example

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if let keys = launchOptions?.keys {
            if keys.contains(.location) {
                NSLog("Launched due to location update");
            } else if keys.contains(.remoteNotification) {
                NSLog("Launched due to remote notification");
            }
        } else {
            NSLog("Launched manually");
        }

    }
```

For more details please read the official apple documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/responding_to_the_launch_of_your_app#2922740